SonarLint IntelliJ IDEA Configuration Error: MalformedJsonException - "Use JsonReader.setLenient(true)
Encountered an issue while configuring SonarLint in IntelliJ IDEA. After binding SonarLint to my SonarQube server and clicking "Next" on the token configuration screen, I received the following error:
Failed to connect to the server. Please check the configuration.
Cause: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException:
Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 2 column 6 path $
SonarLint Version: 10.12.0.79769
IntelliJ IDEA Version: IntelliJ IDEA 2024.1 (Ultimate Edition)
The SonarQube server is reachable via the browser, and the token is valid.
How can I fix or debug this further? Is there a way to make SonarLint more lenient with JSON parsing?

This error typically happens when the HTTP client tries to parse as JSON a response that is definitely not JSON - usually, it’s an HTML page with the proxy authentication error.
SonarLint relies on the proxy settings set in the IDE. You can also check this documentation page for SonarLint for further configuration options.
